# Insert images from folder into cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert all the images of a folder, one by one, to incrementing cells in Excel.

For example, picture 1 should be inserted in cell E1, then picture 2 in cell E2, etc.

My code can only insert one picture from this directory in a hardcoded cell:

```
Sub Insert()

Dim myPict As Picture
Dim PictureLoc As String
PictureLoc = "C:\MyFolder\Picture1.png"

With Range("E1")
    Set myPict = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureLoc)
    .RowHeight = myPict.Height
    myPict.Top = .Top
    myPict.Left = .Left
    myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objPic As Picture
    Dim rngCell As Range

    strFolder = "C:\Users\Domenic\Pictures\Saved Pictures\" 'change the path accordingly
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    End If

    Set rngCell = Range("E1") 'starting cell

    strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "*.png", vbNormal) 'filter for .png files

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
        With objPic
            .Left = rngCell.Left
            .Top = rngCell.Top
            .Height = rngCell.RowHeight
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1, 0)
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

To set the LockAspectRatio property to False, and set the width of the picture to the width of the cell...

```
With objPic
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = False
    .Left = rngCell.Left
    .Top = rngCell.Top
    .Width = rngCell.Width
    .Height = rngCell.RowHeight
    .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End With
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how would you modify it to pic up multiple image files like JPG, GIF TIFF etc? Would you append to strFileName?  or would you just repeat the last half for each file type you wanted to add?

Comment: You can use `Dir(strFolder & "*.*", vbNormal)` to loop through all files, and then test for the desired file extensions within the `Do While/Loop`.

Comment: Thanks, this does put all the images in the folder, but for some reason some images end up getting only half of the width of the cell, while others get the whole size. The images all have the exact same dimensions: 4672 x 1800 pixels.

Comment: You can set the width of the picture to the width of the cell, but you would have to set the LockAspectRatio property of its ShapeRange object to False. So the picture would fill the entire cell, but it's aspect ratio won't be the same as the original.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Could you provide code both with aspect ratio and without in your answer?