# Excel - adding images to cell

Tags: excel

I need to insert images in the top right hand corner of cells in a column.
The code given by Domenic here:
[Excel-Insert images from folder into cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525719/excel-insert-images-from-folder-into-cells)
works very well for top left hand corner.
What change do I need to make to get the images to the top right hand corner?
The images have different width sizes.
I tried changing the following line

```
.Left = rngCell.Left
```

to

```
.Left = rngCell.Left + rngCell.Width - .Width
```

But the images were not aligned. The first one was on the top right hand corner but others were at different points in their cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this section:

```
With objPic
    .Left = rngCell.Left
    .Top = rngCell.Top
    .Height = rngCell.RowHeight
    .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End With
```

to:

```
With objPic
    .Height = rngCell.RowHeight
    .Left = rngCell.Left + rngCell.Width - objPic.Width
    .Top = rngCell.Top
    .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End With
```

Comment: Olly, I tried that but images were not aligned. What would cause that? I suppose if the images had the same width then they would have aligned.

Comment: Also the images retain the aspect ratio in the cell and are not displayed at full size. So that is all good. All that is required is that they be aligned to the right hand corner.

Comment: What do you mean, they were not aligned? This adjustment to the code will right align the images with the cells... You DID change the order of the lines of code, to make the size (height) adjustment BEFORE the left alignment, didn't you?

Comment: That did it Olly. I did NOT change the order of the lines. Thank you Sir. Much appreciated