# Trying to Replicate the 'IMAGE()' Function from Google Sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need a quick and visual way to see if my Image URLs are correct and representative of the data given. I need a function (like Google's 'Image()') to quickly preview a URL image.

So far, I've been able to load an image with my own 'image()' function but it places the image as a floating element. Is there a way to force the image inside the cell and expand the cell to the image height and width of 100x100? << This allows me to fill and see results for multiple rows of data.

Here is my VBA code so far:

```
Function Image(url As String)
    Dim pic As Picture
    Dim pcell As Range
        Set pcell = Application.Caller
    
        Set pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(url)
        With pic
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = False
        .Left = pcell.Left
        .Top = pcell.Top
        .Width = pcell.Width
        .Height = pcell.RowHeight
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With

    Exit Function
End Function
```

I'm not super familiar with VBA. Please explain any coded solution.

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525719/insert-images-from-folder-into-cells

Comment: `pcell.Width = .Width` etc  There is no method for putting an image "inside" a cell in Excel - all you can do is position it "over" the cell.  `xlMove` is probably better than `xlMoveAndSize`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, definitely brings me closer to a solution! I'd prefer it expanded/resized the cell to fit a fixed-width image.

Comment: To Excel the photos are always free floating, they will not belong "in" a cell.  This only anchors it to the cells location.  You will need to play around with the setting the row.Height and Column.Width of the cells to get it to be the correct size.  The size of the cell will need to be set prior to inserting the photo.

Comment: @ScottCraner So, the questions 'updated' formula is probably the best replication of Google Sheets 'Image()' available in Excel? I would just have to format my columns and rows before running the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot achieve this with a function used in a cell formula. You can google "what you can and cannot do with udf in excel vba". One of the things you cannot do is resize cells if called from withing excel (i.e. as a formula in a cell). It would work if you call the function from within vba. In code you can identify how the function is called via `Application.Caller` which will return a reference to the cell if called from within excel.

A work-around to your problem is to use some worksheet events such as `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`. In this case you would enter the url(s) in your desired cell(s) and run the procedure when you double-click the desired cell. Try code such as this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cl As Range
    Set cl = Target
    On Error Resume Next
    If cl.Value <> "" Then
        Dim pic As Picture
        'Me.Pictures.Delete
        Set pic = Me.Pictures.Insert(cl.Value)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not pic Is Nothing Then
            Cancel = True
            With pic
                .Left = cl.Left
                .Top = cl.Top
                cl.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 20
                .Width = cl.Width
                cl.EntireRow.RowHeight = .Height
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Please note that you don't have to set the picture height as it will be resized automatically by as the aspect ratio is locked for pictures (by default). Also note `.ColumnWidth` and `.RowHeight` do not necessarily have the same unit (they don't on my computer) so you have to be careful with this. *May be someone can shed more light into this issue*.

One more thing you need to keep in mind if you choose to go with the function option, is that every time the function is recalculated, you will get a new picture added on top of what had already been added so you have to find a way to avoid this.