# use Google Apps Script to save/export Google Sheet as XLS Excel but preserve images

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-excel

I've got a Google Sheet that has product info, including links to images for each item that's saved to our Google Drive.

Here's a sample [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q6oWsRDoSqnHhqwliY6ZJ24XMhQKunUbj_iDfCpXa3c/edit#gid=0).

The images are also shown on the Google Sheet. This allows people to see the items when they're using the Sheet, and also they can print to PDF or whatever.

If it matters, the way we're showing the images is by using GS's "Image" function with a link to the file.

However, some people have use cases where they want to export/save this info to an Excel file, but they still want the images shown.

Is there any way to do this with Google Apps Script or any other method? I've already done some research and couldn't find a lot of info on this.

Comment: "with Google Apps Script or any other method?" Are they using the UI Menu File > Download > Excel?

Comment: Yes, using the UI Menu File > Download > Excel, we get a file without images. We've also tried different variations of copying and pasting, from the Google Sheet to a blank Excel spreadsheet. (Copying/pasting to *another* Google Sheet *does* work.) So I don't think there's a way to do this via the UI.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Here's how I can tell that the xlsx downloaded via UI works. I downloaded the file, and the uploaded the .xlsx to Google Drive, I opened this new uploaded file in Google Sheets and all the images are there. I don't have excel to test it, but it should work.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't try that. The problem is, when you open the XLS file in *Excel*, you can't see the images. We're working with people who're using Excel, not Google Sheets.

Answer (score -1):

I understand what is going on now. I tested your file in an online excel viewer. The issue you are having is that your images are not pasted into the Google sheet. They are being fetched from Google Drive using the URL of the image in Drive and the formula:`IMAGE(URL)`. Excel does **not** have that `IMAGE` formula. So it gives you `#NAME?` error,because it can't understand the formula.

I reccommend you go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62804789/15557282) for how to replicate the `IMAGE()` function from Google Sheets in Excel.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at this from an Excel/VB angle.

Comment: The question asked how to use apps script to export google sheets as xlsx with images “in cell”, so a vba script does not solve the problem.